# How do I fix adding multiple items based on their name to an array list using the same function?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have created a system where if you click a button it adds the buttons textContent to an array list. The problem is I made sure you could not click the same button multiple times to add it to the list. If you click a different button though, it does not add it to the list but instead the console outputs 'item already in list'. Along with adding the text content of the first item of the li list.

Code:

```js
const cartItems = [];
        
        function cartAmount() {
            var itemsInCart;
        
            itemsInCart = document.getElementById('cartamount');
        
            if(cartItems.length >= 1) {
                itemsInCart.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        
            itemsInCart.innerHTML = cartItems.length;
        }
        
        function addCart() {
            var itemVal, aVal, a;
        
            a = document.getElementById('item');
            aVal = a.value;
            itemVal = a.textContent;
        
            if(cartItems.includes(a.textContent)) {
                console.log('item already in cart');
            } else {
                cartItems.push(itemVal);
              //  cartAmount();
                console.log('added Item to cart');
            }
        }
```

```html
<ul id="wrapper">
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item" onclick="addCart()">Drum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item" onclick="addCart()">Stand Off</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item" onclick="addCart()">Seat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item" onclick="addCart()">Drum Sticks</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item" onclick="addCart()">Symbols</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item" onclick="addCart()">Keyboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item" onclick="addCart()">High Hat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item" onclick="addCart()">Bass Drum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item" onclick="addCart()">Snare Drum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item" onclick="addCart()">Jake Inator</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: well, someone gave a correct answer.. it's customary to mark em

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use different ids for the items so you can distinguishes between items:

**Run the next snippet which show a solution to your problem.**

```js
 const cartItems = [];
    
    function addCart(id) {
        var itemVal, aVal, a;
    
        a = document.getElementById(id);
        aVal = a.value;
        itemVal = a.textContent;
        console.log(itemVal);

    
        if(cartItems.includes(a.textContent)) {
            console.log('item already in cart');
        } else {
            cartItems.push(itemVal);
            console.log('added Item to cart');
        }
    }
```

```html
 <ul id="wrapper">
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item1" onclick="addCart(this.id)">Drum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item2" onclick="addCart(this.id)">Stand Off</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item3" onclick="addCart(this.id)">Seat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item4" onclick="addCart(this.id)">Drum Sticks</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item5" onclick="addCart(this.id)">Symbols</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item6" onclick="addCart(this.id)">Keyboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item7" onclick="addCart(this.id)">High Hat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item8" onclick="addCart(this.id)">Bass Drum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item9" onclick="addCart(this.id)">Snare Drum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="item10" onclick="addCart(this.id)">Jake Inator</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because all of your "a" tags have the same id. An id is supposed to be unique so you want to give a different id to each of the items you want users to be able to add to the cart.

Then inside your js function you need to update it so you get the event object as a parameter and get the element that was clicked on through it

````
function addCart(e) {
        var itemVal, aVal, a;
    
        aVal = e.target.value;
        itemVal = e.target.textContent;
    
        if(cartItems.includes(itemVal)) {
            console.log('item already in cart');
        } else {
            cartItems.push(itemVal);
            cartAmount();
            console.log('added Item to cart');
        }
    }```
````